# Error uploading file: TypeError: source is not async iterable

Tags: ipfs, ipfs-http-client

Is there an issue with IPFS. nothing works

I get this ERROR when running ipfs daemon

2022-11-05T01:21:38.715+0100    ERROR   tcp-tpt tcp/tcp.go:59   failed set keepalive period     {"error": "set tcp4 192.168.1.6:4001->34.211.25.159:41218: setsockopt: invalid argument"}

```
import * as IPFS from 'ipfs-core'

const setURI = async (file, callback) => {
  try {
    const ipfs = await IPFS.create()
    const { cid } = await ipfs.add(file)
    console.info(cid)
   // callback(url)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error uploading file: ', error)
  }  
}
export {
    setURI
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the latest version of Babel: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/15145

A workaround is to downgrade by adding this to `package.json`:

```json
  "resolutions": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "7.17.12"
  },
```

Comment: Thank you. good to know. I finally switched to pinata SDK to handle the upload to IPFS